# Unwanted blobs at the end of Adobe Illustrator calligraphy brush strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, wacom

I am currently inking a pencil sketch scanned into my computer and placed in a layer on an Adobe illustrator file. I am using a 3pt calligraphic brush with the size variation set to pressure 3pt. The stroke weight is 1pt. Whenever I finish a line, an unsightly blob is created rather like what would happen if a fountain pen was filled with too much ink. Is there any thing that can be done to counter act this? It is somewhat frustrating.

It doesn't happen all the time and may be to do with the age of the tablet. It is a Wacom GD tablet.

Comment: Hi Jonathan Beech, can you please attach an image so that we can better understand and visualize your issue, to have a better chance of being able to help you, Thanks.